# Is this a correct construction?

Tags: grammaticality

is

> Some people theorized online that it could have been because of a difference in the type of shoes worn by the players on the field, I personally prefer divine intervention.

a correct construction?

When compared with for example

> Some people theorized online that it could have been because of a difference in the type of shoes worn by the players on the field, I personally prefer divine intervention as an explanation.

The question is not which sounds best, rather if they are correct construction or not?

Comment: They each sound a bit tortured when written out but as speech they are adequate as to construction.

Comment: If you keep it a single sentence, it should start with *Although* or *While*. Or you can join the two thoughts with *.... on the field; however, I ...* or *...on the field, but I ...*

Comment: Besides needing more of a connector than a comma alone, you also could clarify "personally prefer divine intervention."  Do you prefer divine intervention for yourself, or do you prefer *the explanation* of divine intervention?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Isn't that what the second version says? So the question is whether he needs to be explicit in the second clause.

Comment: I personally think there's little ambiguity. The context makes it clear what you prefer divine intervention for.

Comment: Now with the second version, I am content.